Undefined reference to mathematical functions when called with variables but work fine without
I have a small C program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    // this works
    printf("%lf", sin(3.14/2));
    // this doesn't work
    float x = 3.14/2;
    printf("%lf", sin(x));
    return 0;
}

And I am compiling it using Cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(HelloWorld C)
add_executable(HelloWorld main.c)
set_property(TARGET HelloWorld PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS "-lm")

Why does printf("%lf", sin(3.14/2)); work without issues but using sin on a variable, no matter if double or float, does not?

Not an expert in CMAKE, but I'd consider -lm a linker flag rather than compiler. Try replacing COMPILE_FLAGS with LINK_FLAGS

@EugeneSh. You are right, that works
